# Duplicate tableview cells in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

I have a tableview that is populated using a Parse query. However, all of the cells are loaded with the first object from the query results array. For example, if the query returns [User1,User2] the two cells in the tableview will show "User1". What am I doing wrong?

Here's a gist of the file:
https://gist.github.com/jtansley/2329c6fa4baa63f48ee2

Hopefully the issue is obvious to experienced programmers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code, I think you don't know that **findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock** is a function run in another thread but main thread.

Therefore, in **func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell** , your change in UI would be wrong.

One more things, to improve your app performance, you shouldn't query in cellForRowAtIndexPath! Do your queries in viewDidLoad instead. Fill your database on Parse to an array, then load it inside cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

I couldn't code for you since I'm hanging out with my gf. ;)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm new to iOS programming. What do you mean by change in UI? Is the issue with a segue?

Comment: I mean that you updated the textField of tableView cell in another thread but main thread.